# How can I add 3D glitch effects to a model in Blender

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I create an animation like the example below with Geometry Nodes, or is there an easier method using other tools in Blender?

The model is cut horizontally into 3 or 4 parts (tearing), and then random glitch effects are added to the parts (voxelized, randomly monochrome colored, strange texture, shifted to the left or right).

Full animation: https://www.shutterstock.com/tr/video/clip-1078984763-3d-glitch-david-head-on-pink-background

Screenshot 1
[image: glitch 1]

Screenshot 2
[image: glitch 2]

Screenshot 3
[image: glitch 3]

Comment: I guess this effect is easier done in the compositor than with Geometry Nodes because, as in the real world, it is the camera/signal that is glitching, not the model (=image <=> geometry).

Comment: It seems like every glitch is made with geometry

Comment: yes, you're right, the geometry is glitched. It's better visible if you just look at single frames. That's why you should add screenshots to your question ;-) --  It looks like the model is sliced horizontally, and then random effects are added (voxelized, random monochrome colored, weird texture, shifted to left or right)